# Deleting an ID from the wp_post table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I use this SQL query to get me all the posts that don't have a photo, it shows me 2010 posts, however with what SQL command I can delete those 2010 posts

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
 WHERE 1 = 1 AND wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL 
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Comment: i use mysql ( phpmyadmin )

Comment: `... FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON ...`: shouldn't one of these tables be `wp_postmeta` instead?

Comment: Why should it be wp_postmeta?

Comment: `wp_postmeta` exists among the conditions but missing within the tables' list. Seems you misprinted one of wp_posts by intention of wp_postmeta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using `EXISTS` :

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts 
 WHERE EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 1
      FROM wp_posts wp1
      LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp2 ON wp1.ID = wp2.post_id AND wp2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
     WHERE wp2.post_id IS NULL
       AND wp1.post_type = 'post'
       AND (wp1.post_status = 'publish' OR wp1.post_status = 'private')
       AND wp1.ID = wp_posts.ID
     GROUP BY wp1.ID
     )
```

or an `INNER JOIN` :

```
DELETE w 
  FROM wp_posts w JOIN
    (
    SELECT wp1.ID
      FROM wp_posts wp1
      LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp2 ON wp1.ID = wp2.post_id AND wp2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
     WHERE wp2.post_id IS NULL
       AND wp1.post_type = 'post'
       AND (wp1.post_status = 'publish' OR wp1.post_status = 'private')
     GROUP BY wp1.ID
     ) w2
     ON w.ID = w2.ID
```